# Send a variable from one page to another in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to send a variable value from one page to another.

I have used `include("form-eidtable.php")` in `user-edit.php` at bottom of the page,

Look at the image below:

[image]

I dont know how can how can i do this. I am just trying to send the value. IS there any way in Javascript in which i can $_GET a variable from PHP page? or is there any way i can do this through PHP.

Really stuck dont know what should i do.

Thank you! (In Advance)

Comment: Instead of a code snapshot, make it a practice to copy-paste 'relevant' part of code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your `var redirecturl=..` properly like this in your js function

```
var redirecturl = "user-edit.php?useredit=<?php echo $uid;?>";
```

Comment: Thank you, i think the problem is what you said.

Answer (score 1):

No need of Javascript.
In your `form-editable.php`, just start a session and copy the desired variable into `$_SESSION[]` variable.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
```

And then use it in `user-edit.php`. Note that here also you will have to start a session.

```
session_start();
$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
```

[More on PHP sessions.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Comment: i can not edit the session. As the session value is already set.Is there any another way?

Comment: @user3201500 Do you mean `$_SESSION['uid']` is already set? Then use `$_SESSION['something_else']`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a a session

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
```

Read more about sessions here.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Means session is also not working. So i am trying cookie. But again its not helping. Its not updating the cookie.

Comment: session_start();                                                           $_SESSION['thing'] = $uid; remeber to start the session

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_GET` like that, but you have a syntax error in your Javascript after the PHP runs.  You are closing out the string in your `redirecturl` and then having PHP `echo $uid;`.  This results in Javascript of `useredit="344`  If you either wrap the PHP block inside the quote or add a `+` between the JS and the PHP (so long as your `$uid` is numeric`) it should work without using sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions or cookies the main advantage of the cookie is the fact that the cookie will remain even after the client will close his browser. I won't recommend to use a variable in a GET method and use it without proper validation. This will make your site vulnerable to sql injection attacks. If you  want to access it from javascript you can use window.location. But as a rule of thumb please validate your GET variables before using them in your sql queries.