# How to access a mysql variable value on another page

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in php and want to ask how can I access a variable on another page.
My code:

```
<?php
    $username = "ADMIN";
    $host = "localhost";
    $password = "ADMIN";
    $database = "USER";
    $sname =  $_POST['signupname'];
    $susername =  $_POST['susername'];
    $spassword =  $_POST['spassword'];
    $gender =  $_POST['gender'];
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
    if(isset($_POST["signup"])) {
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `USER`.`INFO` (`UID`, `NAME`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`, `GENDER`, `BDAY`, `BMONTH`, `BYEAR`, `STATUS`, `LAST-ACTIVE`) VALUES (NULL, '$sname', '$susername', '$spassword', '$gender', '', '', '', '', NULL);");
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('../SSTEPS1010101/birthdaycheck1010101.php');</script>";
    }
?>
```

and other page code:-

```
<?php
    require '../SIGNUP/connects1010101.php';
    $bday = $_POST["bday"];
    $bmonth = $_POST["bmonth"];
    $byear = $_POST["byear"];
    if (isset($_POST["snext"])) {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `USER`.`INFO` SET `BDAY` = '$bday', `BMONTH` = '$bmonth', `BYEAR` = '$byear' WHERE `info`.`USERNAME` = '$susername;'");
    }
    echo "$susername";
?>
```

How can I access `$susername` on other page?
I am using $_SESSIONS["susername"]; and echo-ing it on the first page and it is working but on the other page the $_SESSIONS["susername"]; is not working.

Comment: What is the name of your first file? You can just type `include "firstfile.php";` in the second file.

Comment: include first file in other page .

Comment: Use a `select`, not an `update`. You also are open to SQL injections and should be hashing the passwords.

Comment: The required file I have added is the first page

Comment: I haven't gone for SQL Injections yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send a variable from one page to another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21774109/send-a-variable-from-one-page-to-another-in-php)

Comment: How is the "other page" being accessed?

Comment: By require statement

Comment: if you require the page where `username` is in, in another page, `username` will be available in that page.

Comment: But not only username, other variables like $example = $_POST["example"]; are not accessible

Comment: @ChMuhammadSohaib what is the name of the file with the username?

Comment: mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `USER`.`INFO` SET `BDAY` = '$bday', `BMONTH` = '$bmonth', `BYEAR` = '$byear' WHERE `info`.`USERNAME` = '$susername;'");  ... What Is This .... Just Check First.... Your Self....

Comment: WHERE info.USERNAME = '$susername;'"); ..... ???

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Use Session:

**Fisrt.php**

```
session_start();
 $username = "Max";
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
echo $username; //Output: Max
```

**Use In Another Page**

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['username']; //Output: Max
```

> 2. include

You can, but the variable in your last include will overwrite the variable in your first one:

**myfirstfile.php**

```
$name = 'max';
```

**mysecondfile.php**

```
$city = 'xyz';
```

**test.php**

```
include 'myfirstfile.php';
echo $name;

include 'mysecondfile.php';
echo $city;
```

**Output:**

> max
>
> xyz

Comment: I haven't overwritten it with any other variable.

Comment: where is overwritten ... ?

Comment: even if it is overwritten it will still be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use global keyword or sessions

```
global $susername;
```

or With **Session**

```
session_start();
$username = "bla bla bla";
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
```

**another page:**

```
session_start();
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
echo $username;
```

Answer (score 0):

You include files using `require*` and `include*` functions, and when you include file you need to specify the correct paths to the file.

**set  your PHP to display errors**

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

**How to include files**

```
// including a file which is in the same directory
require_once ('somefile.php');

 // include a file that is one directories back
require_once ('../somefile.php');
require_once ('../directory/somefile.php');

 // include a file that is two directories back
require_once ('../../somefile.php');
require_once ('../../directory/somefile.php');

// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try THis ...

**connects1010101.php File**

```
<?php
//connects1010101.php File


    $username = "ADMIN";
    $host = "localhost";
    $password = "ADMIN";
    $database = "USER";

    $sname =  $_POST['signupname'];
    $susername =  $_POST['susername'];
    $spassword =  $_POST['spassword'];
    $gender =  $_POST['gender'];

    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

    if(isset($_POST["signup"])) {

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `USER`.`INFO` (`UID`, `NAME`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`, `GENDER`, `BDAY`, `BMONTH`, `BYEAR`, `STATUS`, `LAST-ACTIVE`) VALUES (NULL, '$sname', '$susername', '$spassword', '$gender', '', '', '', '', NULL)");

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('../SSTEPS1010101/birthdaycheck1010101.php');</script>";
    }
?>
```

**AnotherFile.php**

```
<?php

    include  '../SIGNUP/connects1010101.php';  //connects1010101.php include 
    global $susername;

    $bday = $_POST["bday"];
    $bmonth = $_POST["bmonth"];
    $byear = $_POST["byear"];

    if (isset($_POST["snext"])) {

    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `USER`.`INFO` SET `BDAY` = '$bday', `BMONTH` = '$bmonth', `BYEAR` = '$byear' WHERE `USERNAME` = '$susername' ");
    }

    echo "$susername";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You everyone. The main Problem Was in redirecting.
My Old Code:-

```
<?php
    $username = "ADMIN";
    $host = "localhost";
    $password = "ADMIN";
    $database = "USER";
    $sname =  $_POST['signupname'];
    $susername =  $_POST['susername'];
    $spassword =  $_POST['spassword'];
    $gender =  $_POST['gender'];
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
    if(isset($_POST["signup"])) {
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `USER`.`INFO` (`UID`, `NAME`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`, `GENDER`, `BDAY`, `BMONTH`, `BYEAR`, `STATUS`, `LAST-ACTIVE`) VALUES (NULL, '$sname', '$susername', '$spassword', '$gender', '', '', '', '', NULL);");
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('../SSTEPS1010101/birthdaycheck1010101.php');</script>";
    }
?>
```

Other Page:-

```
<?php
    require '../SIGNUP/connects1010101.php';
    $bday = $_POST["bday"];
    $bmonth = $_POST["bmonth"];
    $byear = $_POST["byear"];
    if (isset($_POST["snext"])) {
    mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `USER`.`INFO` SET `BDAY` = '$bday', `BMONTH` = '$bmonth', `BYEAR` = '$byear' WHERE `info`.`USERNAME` = '$susername;'");
    }
    echo "$susername";
?>
```

My New First Page code:-

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = "ADMIN";
$host = "localhost";
$password = "chmuhammadsohaib123";
$database = "USER";
$sname =  $_POST['signupname'];
$susername =  $_POST['susername'];
$spassword =  $_POST['spassword'];
$gender =  $_POST['gender'];
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);
if(isset($_POST["signup"])) {
mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `USER`.`INFO` (`UID`, `NAME`, `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD`, `GENDER`, `BDAY`, `BMONTH`, `BYEAR`, `STATUS`, `LAST-ACTIVE`) VALUES (NULL, '$sname', '$susername', '$spassword', '$gender', '', '', '', '', NULL);");
$snusername = $_SESSION["susername"] = $susername;
}
if (isset($_POST["signup"])) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('../SSTEPS1010101/birthdaycheck1010101.php');</script>";
}?>
```

Other Page:-

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once ('../SIGNUP/connects1010101.php');
$bday = $_POST["bday"];
$bmonth = $_POST["bmonth"];
$byear = $_POST["byear"];
$snusername = $_SESSION["susername"];
if (isset($_POST["snext"])) {
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `USER`.`INFO` SET `BDAY` = '$bday', `BMONTH` = '$bmonth', `BYEAR` = '$byear' WHERE `info`.`USERNAME` = '$snusername;'");
}?>
```

The main problem was in the JS script I was using. Thanks to all guyz who answered.